# How to get memory speed when dmidecode says "Speed: Unknown" and lshw just hangs

Tags: linux, memory, debian-squeeze

I'd like to get memory speed information, but `dmidecode -t memory` says `Speed: Unknown` and `lshw` prints out string `DMI` and then does nothing until I kill it.

Is there other way to get this information? Or some magic parameters for `lshw` or `dmidecode` to force them to actualy do what they're supposed to?

```
root@server:~# dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0027
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 2048 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM A1
        Bank Locator: BANK0
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer0
        Serial Number: SerNum0
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
        Part Number: PartNum0

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0027
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM B1
        Bank Locator: BANK1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer1
        Serial Number: SerNum1
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
        Part Number: PartNum1
```

.

```
root@server:~# lshw -version
B.02.14
root@server:~# lshw
DMI
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `dmesg` to pull this type of information from the kernel

```
root@server ~]# dmesg |grep -i memory |grep core
[    1.518759] nouveau  [     DRM] 0: core 208MHz shader 416MHz memory 100MHz voltage 1200mV fanspeed 100%
[    1.518762] nouveau  [     DRM] 1: core 460MHz shader 920MHz memory 400MHz voltage 1200mV fanspeed 100%
[    1.518764] nouveau  [     DRM] c: core 459MHz shader 918MHz memory 399MHz voltage 1200mV
[    2.141818] nouveau  [     DRM] 0: core 208MHz shader 416MHz memory 100MHz voltage 1200mV fanspeed 100%
[    2.141821] nouveau  [     DRM] 1: core 460MHz shader 920MHz memory 400MHz voltage 1200mV fanspeed 100%
[    2.141823] nouveau  [     DRM] c: core 459MHz shader 918MHz memory 399MHz voltage 1200mV
```

dmesg is good for pulling any device info;
 ie `dmesg |grep -i scsi` or `dmesg |grep -i usb` or just `dmesg| more` to see it all

Comment: I had no luck with `dmesg`. Also from your snippet it looks like info about graphic card, not main memory.

Comment: oops your right about dmesg snippet. for lshw try updating to 2.16+